# QSlider acting like pushers, how to connect to slot that keeps doing something as long a QSlider.isSliderDown() is True?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside6

I have aQt PySide6 app with a centralWidget taken by a Vispy Canvas (OpenGL).

I try to pilot parameters azimuth and elevation of the camera showing the 3D OpenGL environment shown in central widget of the main window.

I have two QSliders in a DockWidget (range -1.0, 1.0, default value 0.0). I try to connect their isPressed() to a method in which I first move the camera by delta increment based on myslider.value(), then test if myslider.isSliderDown() is True, and if so recursively calls the same method. Else (slider released) it sets back the slider at its origin: my slider.setValue(0).

I so would like to have a kind of joystick behaviour. Wen pressed and dragged, the camera rotates/moves, more or less rapidly following the displacement of the slider, and then stops when slider is released, this one jumping back to center position/value.

All I have with this implementation is an infinite loop as soon as I press and drag the slider. Releasing it does not stop the loop.

Why mySlider.isSliderDown() does not reflect the status of the slider? Am I, because of the recursive call, blocked inside the first slot connection call, never going out to reevaluate GUI state?

If so, how should I code this?

Comment: This doesn't seem a valid approach, and looping blocks the UI, but in order to properly help you we need a valid [mre].

Comment: I know this would be a good thing, but currently my code is quite large already and rather interdependent. I have difficulties to just rewrite a simple working example without including a lot of classes and subclasses of my own. Is there no suggestion about how to achieve this kind of thing: having an action repeated as long as a gui object is pressed/clicked and stop when released?

Comment: Hint: if you want to perform some action periodically while some GUI element is pressed try using a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html).

Comment: @GregVDS The suggestion is using timed events and properly use signals and slots. Other than that, we cannot randomly help you without knowing *anything* of your code. From your description, you don't need to include anything else, just a basic UI with the slider and the function(s) that do what you're actually doing. Everything else would be completely irrelevant for what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint at QTimer @G.M.!!! That did it. I'll edit my post to quickly show how I did it.

Comment: Note that rather than editing your question to show the solution it's perfectly acceptable (and preferable) to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @G.M. I modify this asap

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with QTimer:

```py
...
self.cameraModTimer = QTimer(self)
self.cameraModTimer.timeout.connect(self.updateCamera)

self.fovSlider = CameraParamSlider(Qt.Vertical, self, fovLabel, "fov", 1.0e3)
self.fovSlider.sliderPressed.connect(self.startCameraUpdate)
self.fovSlider.sliderReleased.connect(self.stopCameraUpdate)
...
```

with

```py
    @Slot()
    def updateCamera(self):
        if self.fovSlider.isSliderDown() is True:
            self.fovSlider.updateParam()

    @Slot()
    def startCameraUpdate(self):
        """
        Start the QTimer that will trigger updateParam as long as it's not stopped
        """
        self.cameraModTimer.start()

    @Slot()
    def stopCameraUpdate(self):
        """
        Stop the QTimer that triggered updateParam. This also sets back the sliders
        to their default position and calls a last time updateParam to refresh
        sliders labels after having been reset.
        """
        self.cameraModTimer.stop()
        self.fovSlider.setValue(0.0)
        self.fovSlider.updateParam()
```